# Rabbi Avigdor Miller's quote about one's face and soul

Tags: sources-mekorot, jewish-books, soul, face

Rabbi Avigdor Miller *zt"l,* says, *“Your **face** is like a screen and your **soul** like a projector which projects on your face the glory of the human soul, which has in it the greatness of Hashem."* (10 steps to Greatness, tape #706)

Are there any *sefarim* or *gemaras* that speak about the connection between one's soul anyone and his face?

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=KIE_AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA44&lpg=PA44&dq=%D7%A0%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%94+%D7%A2%D7%9C+%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D&source=bl&ots=SjIZz_5DIG&sig=nqGefKAfVcyixx9YUTdGn1AKPC0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=3SDiVL39OsargwTYsYLAAw&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%D7%A0%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%94%20%D7%A2%D7%9C%20%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D&f=false

Comment: @GershonGold: Please tell me what it says in english.

Comment: It says in English the same thing Rabbi Miller says.

Answer (score 1):

Rabbi Avigdor Miller told Rabbi Simcha Bunim Cohen towards the end of his life that he was able to see the Tzelem Elokim in every person, even a goy.

I heard this from Rabbi Simcha Bunim himself, with that said, and having seen it himself. I don't need to see this in any other sefer, I trust Rabbi Avigdor Miller.

Comment: how do you know he didn't see something that he interpreted as tzelem elokim.. He might've interpreted it wrongly

Comment: I agree that  Rabbi Avigdor Miller saw tzelem elokim in everyone. @barlop when you've reached the level of Rabbi Miller, believe me, you can tell.

Comment: @TurkHill I think an answer is that tzelem elokim can refer to great values like integrity and caring. And sometimes one can get a strong impression that somebody is a good person, and thus manifests that or some divine attributes. And some say they can see a spark of goodness in everybody.

Comment: @barlop Yes, I agree.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of seeing one's projected onto one's body, particularly the face, is found in the Zohar 2:70a and explained by Rav Moshe Miller [here](https://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/380238/jewish/Face-of-Justice.htm)

> "Now see to it" - look at the hair [which includes] the lines on the
> forehead and the eyebrows. "From among all the people" - the eyes
> [which includes] the layers of the eyes [i.e. the pupil, iris, and the
> white of the eye] and the lines under the eye. "Men of stature" -
> those who have the ability to stand in the halls of the King [this
> alludes to] the glow of the face, at the face itself, [and] the lines
> and folds of the face, and the beard. "Who hate corruption…" - the
> hands, the lines and marks of the hands.

When Moshe Rabbenu was charged with finding judges for the nation, he looked at their faces to see the 'projection' of their soul.